# Is there a lightweight photo viewer made with Qt?

Tags: kubuntu, software-recommendation, plasma-5, qt5

While the default photo viewer Gwenview is very good, it is also a file manager and has many other features. As a result it is not very lightweight.

Is there a very lightweight photo viewer (that need not have editing capabilities) made with Qt?

Also, is there a (not as resource intensive as Gwenview) photo viewer which has basic editing capabilities (rotate and save, crop and save etc.)?

It does not need to have a lot of editing capabilities like Digikam or Gwenview.

Comment: lightweight photo viewers won't usually offer rotate/crop functions as they are editing functions and not viewing functions (though many rotate for viewing, but don't save; having zoom in functions that achieves 'crop' for a viewer).

Comment: Ok, I will edit my question

Comment: I know that Pix and Eye of MATE are quite lightweight and have basic editing functions, but I was looking for a software made with Qt.

Comment: `lximage-qt` (default of Lubuntu) has some nice features (really useful for bug reporting)

Comment: Is there some objective yardstick for lightweight/heavyweight? This question maybe for suited for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DKBose Well not exactly. Gwenview takes ~5 seconds to open an image, while Xviewer takes ~2 seconds to open the image (in the same machine but in a different operating system). I will definitely give `lximage-qt` a try.

Comment: What is Xviewer? What are your must-have features?

Comment: And do you know of a way to time how long it takes a **GUI** application to load completely? I can't find any that's not sort of subjective.

Comment: @DkBose Yes, that is indeed somewhat subjective, I just counted 1,2, etc. Xviewer is the default image viewer in cinnamon. The must have features are crop, rotate, and zoom. Xviewer does not have crop, by the way. That is why I asked about two softwares, one which is just a very lightweight image viewer, and the other with some editing capabilities, but not as much as gwenview.

Comment: `kolourpaint` in the repos, does have crop but without pixel control.

Comment: BTW, you should try Lubuntu 20.04. It is lighter than even Kubuntu. I would turn off its screensaver altogether or drastically alter the insane defaults.

Comment: I have not upgraded to 20.04 yet, I will definitely try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[qview](https://interversehq.com/qview/) is very minimalistic, and it also has basic editing capabilities.

.deb packages are available at its downloads [page](https://interversehq.com/qview/download/).

Comment: Nice, but no crop function.